# Archer T2U AC600 nano, how can I install it in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wireless, 18.04, adapter, nano

I migrated from Windows 7 to Ubuntu and the computer does not recognize my wireless adapter. And I want to know how to install it, unfortunately it does not have drivers for Linux Ubuntu